# Subject line for farewell email

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to send farewell message via group email to all my colleagues. I am uncertain what to put in subject line.

I've considered:

*Bis wir uns wiedersehen : Until We Meet Again*

*Adios Amigos*

*Adieu*

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your native language?
I speak German and I am a native-English speaker (U.S.), so I would say either "Auf Wiedersehen" in German [already means "until we see each other again"], or simply "Bis dann" [until then], which is less formal.

In English, I would simply say, "Farewell Everyone..." or "Hope to see all of you again!"

Of course, it's always cool to use foreign expressions meaning the same thing like:
Russian: до завтра (da zaftra) = "until tomorrow"
Italian: Ciao = "bye!"
Korean: 안녕! = "bye!"
Japanese: さようなら！= "Sayanora!"
Chinese: 再見！or 再见！ = "Zàijiàn!"
French: Au revoir!
Norwegian: Farvel!
Swedish: Hej då!
Farsi: خداحافظ! 
Greek: Αντίο! = "Antio"
Spanish: ¡Adiós!
Arabic: وداعا!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're writing to colleagues in an office in the US, I'd not go with any of the choices you list, mainly because they are all in foreign languages. Further, because of common usage (or perhaps I should write "misusage"), my own personal experience is that "adios, Amigos" has connotations that are particularly unbusinesslike. The German phrase, or what is listed as its English equivalent in my opinion would be only appropriate if it was definitely known that the absence was temporary, as in a person who had held an internship who was going back to school, and would be returning at the end of the school term.

Otherwise, I'd be most inclined to a subject line that simply summarizes the message, for example "As I get ready to go ", or "Thank you all for the help you've given me."

Comment: Also, to say "bis wir uns wiedersehen" is weird as it is NOT colloquial or standard German...it's more like Google-translated German - no German would ever talk like that. That said, the correct colloquial expression in standard German is simply "Auf Wiedersehen" or "bis dann" or "tschüß" among friends. Also, Grüß Gott is the standard greeting and farewell in Bavaria, or southern Germany, while "servus" is used in Austria.